# Python urllib2 with keep alive

Tags: python, http, urllib2, keep-alive

How can I make a "keep alive" HTTP request using Python's urllib2?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use the [urlgrabber](http://urlgrabber.baseurl.org/) library. This includes an HTTP handler for urllib2 that supports HTTP 1.1 and keepalive:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> from urlgrabber.keepalive import HTTPHandler
>>> keepalive_handler = HTTPHandler()
>>> opener = urllib2.build_opener(keepalive_handler)
>>> urllib2.install_opener(opener)
>>> 
>>> fo = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org')
```

Note: you should use urlgrabber version [3.9.0](http://urlgrabber.baseurl.org/download/urlgrabber-3.9.0.tar.gz) or earlier, as the [keepalive](http://urlgrabber.baseurl.org/help/urlgrabber.keepalive.html) module has been removed in version 3.9.1

There is a [port](https://github.com/wikier/keepalive) of the keepalive module to Python 3.

Comment: In the second line, it seems it should be `from urlgrabber.keepalive import HTTPHandler`

Comment: Thanks @btk - I've now corrected the code accordingly. I've also added a note re which version of urlgrabber to use as per @jwatt's answer.

Comment: [A quick port of it I made to python 3.](http://pastie.org/2388246) Hope if helps someone.

Comment: Thanks @PiPeep - I've added a link to your port in my answer.

Comment: This library has some issues with headers and lacks cookie support. You can fix it by copying from urllib2 and httplib but I'd recommend trying another library.

Comment: @bgw Does the Python 3 port also support python 2?

Comment: @speedplane, I believe it does, however, instead of using that pastie link, you should use https://github.com/wikier/keepalive, which is more actively maintained. I've updated the post. The edit should be visible after it's peer reviewed.

Answer (score 13):

Try [urllib3](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3) which has the following features:

- Re-use the same socket connection for multiple requests (HTTPConnectionPool and HTTPSConnectionPool) (with optional client-side certificate verification).
- File posting (encode_multipart_formdata).
- Built-in redirection and retries (optional).
- Supports gzip and deflate decoding.
- Thread-safe and sanity-safe.
- Small and easy to understand codebase perfect for extending and building upon. For a more comprehensive solution, have a look at Requests.

or a much more comprehensive solution - [Requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) - which supports keep-alive from [version](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/develop/HISTORY.rst) 0.8.0 (by using urllib3 internally) and has the following [features](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/develop/README.rst):

- Extremely simple HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE Requests.
- Gevent support for Asyncronous Requests.
- Sessions with cookie persistience.
- Basic, Digest, and Custom Authentication support.
- Automatic form-encoding of dictionaries
- A simple dictionary interface for request/response cookies.
- Multipart file uploads.
- Automatc decoding of Unicode, gzip, and deflate responses.
- Full support for unicode URLs and domain names.

Answer (score 6):

Or check out [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html)'s HTTPConnection.

Comment: how to enable keep-alive for HTTPConnection? I tried adding `Connection: Keep-Alive` to both requests and response headers, but `httplib` still reconnects on each request

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately keepalive.py was removed from urlgrabber on 25 Sep 2009 by the following change after urlgrabber was changed to depend on pycurl (which supports keep-alive):

http://yum.baseurl.org/gitweb?p=urlgrabber.git;a=commit;h=f964aa8bdc52b29a2c137a917c72eecd4c4dda94

However, you can still get the last revision of keepalive.py here:

http://yum.baseurl.org/gitweb?p=urlgrabber.git;a=blob_plain;f=urlgrabber/keepalive.py;hb=a531cb19eb162ad7e0b62039d19259341f37f3a6

Answer (score 4):

Note that urlgrabber does not entirely work with python 2.6. I fixed the issues (I think) by making the following modifications in keepalive.py.

In keepalive.HTTPHandler.do_open() remove this

```
     if r.status == 200 or not HANDLE_ERRORS:
         return r
```

And insert this

```
     if r.status == 200 or not HANDLE_ERRORS:
         # [speedplane] Must return an adinfourl object
         resp = urllib2.addinfourl(r, r.msg, req.get_full_url())
         resp.code = r.status
         resp.msg = r.reason
         return resp
```

Comment: Thanks but it would be nice if you explained what this fixed instead of that useless tagged comment.

Comment: The original r and your resp are both <type 'instance'> and both have the same attributes. addinfourl says "class to add info() and geturl() methods to an open file." but the original already has info() and geturl(). Couldn't work out the benefit.

Answer (score 3):

Please avoid collective pain and use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) instead. It will do the right thing by default and use keep-alive if applicable.

Comment: I am working on some NTLM authentication and the Requests NTLM library doesn't work correctly for it. However, the urllib2 NTLM library does work correctly. This question was therefore helpful to me.

Comment: @JeffersonHudson, I was not aware of that. You might have better luck with https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm

Comment: I have already proposed Requests in my answer posted over a year before this one...

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost, fair enough, but what I propose is, let Requests be the default choice.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat similar urlopen() that does keep-alive, though it's not threadsafe.

```
try:
    from http.client import HTTPConnection, HTTPSConnection
except ImportError:
    from httplib import HTTPConnection, HTTPSConnection
import select
connections = {}


def request(method, url, body=None, headers={}, **kwargs):
    scheme, _, host, path = url.split('/', 3)
    h = connections.get((scheme, host))
    if h and select.select([h.sock], [], [], 0)[0]:
        h.close()
        h = None
    if not h:
        Connection = HTTPConnection if scheme == 'http:' else HTTPSConnection
        h = connections[(scheme, host)] = Connection(host, **kwargs)
    h.request(method, '/' + path, body, headers)
    return h.getresponse()


def urlopen(url, data=None, *args, **kwargs):
    resp = request('POST' if data else 'GET', url, data, *args, **kwargs)
    assert resp.status < 400, (resp.status, resp.reason, resp.read())
    return resp
```