# How to stay alive in HTTP/1.1 using python urllib

Tags: python, http, keep-alive

For now I am doing this: (Python3, urllib)

```
url = 'someurl'
headers = '(('HOST', 'somehost'), /  
            ('Connection', 'keep-alive'),/
            ('Accept-Encoding' , 'gzip,deflate'))
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor())
for h in headers:
    opener.addheaders.append(x)
data = 'some logging data' #username, pw etc.
opener.open('somesite/login.php, data)

res = opener.open(someurl)
data = res.read()
... some stuff here...
res1 = opener.open(someurl2)
data = res1.read()
etc.
```

What is happening is this;

I keep getting gzipped responses from server and I stayed logged in (I am fetching some content which is not available if I were not logged in) but I think the connection is dropping between every request opener.open;

I think that because connecting is very slow and it seems like there is new connection every time. Two questions:

a)How do I test if in fact the connection is staying-alive/dying
b)How to make it stay-alive between request for other urls ?

Take care :)

Comment: a) Sniffing the traffic would be a trivial way to check whether you're keeping-alive. Make sure the server supports keepalive as well. As for b), at least in python2.x there was a way to specify a handler that could keepalive, but it didn't seem default.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037406/python-urllib2-with-keep-alive

Comment: Well, first this is python3 and this urlgrabber recommended in the other thread is supposedly for 2.5 and before and second I would prefer to avoid using external libraries for this seemingly simple task; especially because i want to understand how those things work

Answer (score 1):

This will be a very delayed answer, but:

You should see [urllib3](http://code.google.com/p/urllib3). It is for Python 2.x but you'll get the idea when you see their README document.

And yes, urllib by default doesn't keep connections alive, I'm now implementing urllib3 for Python 3 to be staying in my toolbag :)

Answer (score 0):

Just if you didn't know yet, python-requests offer keep-alive feature, thanks to urllib3.