# urllib2 does not read entire page

Tags: python, http, html-parsing, urllib2

A portion of code that I have that will parse a web site does not work.

I can trace the problem to the `.read` function of my urllib2.urlopen object.

```
page = urllib2.urlopen('http://magiccards.info/us/en.html')
data = page.read()
```

Until yesterday, this worked fine; but now the length of the data is always 69496 instead of 122989, however when I open smaller pages my code works fine.

I have tested this on Ubuntu, Linux Mint and windows 7. All have the same behaviour.

I'm assuming that something has changed on the web server; but the page is complete when I use a  web browser. I have tried to diagnose the issue with wireshark but the page is received as complete.

Does anybody know why this may be happening or what I could try to determine the issue?

Comment: If you think it has to do with the web server, how could you do anything?

Comment: This is the error I get with urllib in py3k: `http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(69496 bytes read, 53493 more expected)`

Comment: since a web browser was still able to show the complete page, my code also needed to be able to process en entire page.

Answer (score 4):

The page seems to be misbehaving unless you request the content encoded as gzip. Give this a shot:

```
import urllib2
import zlib

request = urllib2.Request('http://magiccards.info/us/en.html')
request.add_header('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
data = zlib.decompress(response.read(), 16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)
```

As Nathan suggested, you could also use the great [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) library, which accepts gzip by default.

```
import requests

data = requests.get('http://magiccards.info/us/en.html').text
```

Comment: It may be that `keep-alive` had nothing to do with this at all. I need to investigate with Wireshark.

Comment: Yeah, could be. curl supports keep-alive and seems to have the same issue.

Comment: curl has the same issue, but it works if you pass the `--compressed` option.  It's definitely a server issue.

Comment: I added the http header to the request and my code works again. 
Many thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the server is closing connection and you need `keep-alive` to be sent. urllib2 does not have that facility ( :-( ). There used be [urlgrabber](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1037423/18852) which you could use have a HTTPHandler that works alongside with urllib2 opener. But unfortunately, I dont find that working too. At the moment, you could be other libraries, like requests as demonstrated in the other answer or [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/).

```
import httplib2
h = httplib2.Http(".cache")
resp, content = h.request("http://magiccards.info/us/en.html", "GET")
print len(content)
```