# Control number of TCP Connections using python

Tags: python, centos, urllib2, python-multiprocessing

For my college project I am trying to develop a python based traffic generator.I have created 2 CentOS machines on vmware and I am using 1 as my client and 1 as my server machine. I have used IP aliasing technique to increase number of clients and severs using just single client/server machine. Upto now I have created 50 IP alias on my client machine and 10 IP alias on my server machine. I am also using multiprocessing module to generate traffic concurrently from all 50 clients to all 10 servers. I have also developed few profiles(1kb,10kb,50kb,100kb,500kb,1mb) on my server(in /var/www/html directory since I am using Apache Server) and I am using urllib2 to send request to these profiles from my client machine. Next what I want to do is control the number of TCP Connections being established between my client and my server. Like sending 1st 100 requests in just 1 TCP session/connection and then sending next 100 requests in another TCP session/connection and so on... Is it possible to achieve this in python?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python urllib2 with keep alive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037406/python-urllib2-with-keep-alive)

Comment: How can I control TCP Connections here? Like after sending 100 requests using 1 TCP Connection I want to kill that connection,spawn another connection and then send 100 requests again